# Flutter android alarm manager plus not working

Tags: android, flutter, alarmmanager, flutter-dependencies

I was making an alarm app using flutter. I added the flutter package [android_alarm_manager_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus).

I added the package and run the `pub get` and I got the the error below:

```
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_alarm_manager_plus-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\dev\fluttercommunity\plus\androidalarmmanager\FlutterBackgroundExecutor.java:12: error: package io.flutter.embedding.engine does not exist
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
                                  ^
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_alarm_manager_plus-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\dev\fluttercommunity\plus\androidalarmmanager\FlutterBackgroundExecutor.java:13: error: package io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart does not exist
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor;

                                       ^
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_alarm_manager_plus-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\dev\fluttercommunity\plus\androidalarmmanager\FlutterBackgroundExecutor.java:14: error: package io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor does not exist
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor.DartCallback;
                                                    ^
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_alarm_manager_plus-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\dev\fluttercommunity\plus\androidalarmmanager\FlutterBackgroundExecutor.java:15: error: package io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.shim does not exist
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.shim.ShimPluginRegistry;

                                               ^
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_alarm_manager_plus-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\dev\fluttercommunity\plus\androidalarmmanager\FlutterBackgroundExecutor.java:16: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger;
                               ^
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_alarm_manager_plus-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\dev\fluttercommunity\plus\androidalarmmanager\FlutterBackgroundExecutor.java:17: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.JSONMethodCodec;

                               ^
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_alarm_manager_plus-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\dev\fluttercommunity\plus\androidalarmmanager\FlutterBackgroundExecutor.java:18: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
                               ^

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_alarm_manager_plus-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\dev\fluttercommunity\plus\androidalarmmanager\FlutterBackgroundExecutor.java:19: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;

                               ^
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_alarm_manager_plus-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\dev\fluttercommunity\plus\androidalarmmanager\FlutterBackgroundExecutor.java:20: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel does not exist
```

> Full Error Log: https://pastebin.com/SsKqkfMe

I don't know what to do. Help me please.

**Thank You very much**

Comment: Follow these steps https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager_plus#getting-started and after that reinstall your app and even after doing all these steps if you are facing any error than try to change your compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 31